# Bizarre issue with Java 1.6_65 JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

We are facing a a bizarre issue with Java 1.6x (1.6_65 in particular)

We have a ResultSet extractor that has following while loop.

```
int limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE    
int i = 1;
while (i <= limit && rs.next()) {
   //some extraction code.
   .....
   i++
}
```

This code only returns one row from the ResultSet intermittently if we change the order of conditional expressions with `rs.next()` first, like below

```
 int limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE    
 int i = 1;
 while (rs.next() && i <= limit ) {
   //some extraction code.
   .....
   i++
}
```

Issue never occurs, also this happens only in Java 1.6x does not happen 1.7+

Anyone ever faced this issue?

### EDIT

Also one more detail I wanted to point out here is that, issue occurs only if I have

```
int limit = Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

if change this to something like below, issue disappears.

```
int limit = 10000
```

I get 10000 or total records in ResultSet whichever is less.

Comment: Shouldn't it be rs.hasNext()?

Comment: @zerocool No. On `ResultSet`, you call `next()` until it return false.

Comment: Just curious, Why you need Integer.MAX_VALUE check at all? Because Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647 (ie, more than 2000 million), Is your resultset is going to exceed this size? I strongly expecting OutOfMemory error or some performance issues here.

Comment: We have a limit that gets set if the code does not fall in to limit path we just set Integer.MAX_VALUE as limit, I tried to simplify the question here

Comment: just curious, you tested the exact same copy of source code as you copy pasted here (I mean only i++ is in the while loop nothing more, nothing less) and you came to the conclusion that it only works above 1.6x? If so, how do you know it works, printing out i after while loop?

Comment: `ResultSet` is an _interface_, and AFAIK, no implementations ship with the JDK, so the apparent change in functionality most likely is caused by the JDBC driver _implementation_ you're using. What is the backing RDBMS and have you updated to a newer driver?

Comment: @Bela Vizer, no this is excerpt of the code that I have , we changed the underlying JDK for the app server and tested. With `while (i <= limit && rs.next())` issue occurs and `while (rs.next() && i <= limit )` issue does not occur.

Comment: I am not able to attribute this to JDBC driver as it happened with both Vertica and Hana drivers. Also order of boolean expressions should not have any bearing on the jdbc driver. Also issue does not occur in Jdk 1.7+ at all

Comment: Could you share some more code -- how is the result set created / what kind of a query are you running?

Comment: @Mick Unfortunately I can not share the query, I am trying to reproduce this with a simple test program outside the app server, If I am successful I will share it

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is because of this

JDK 6 bug JDK-2213657 : Loop unroll optimization causes incorrect result. (http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7044738)